# Compiling Rocket in Bazel

Tags: rust, bazel, rust-rocket

I'm attempting to get a working prototype of the following scenario:

- Language: Rust (`rustc 1.45.0-nightly (ad4bc3323 2020-06-01)`)
- Framework: Rocket v0.4.4
- Build Tool: Bazel
- Platform: Mac OS X / Darwin x64

Running `bazel build //web-api` yields the below error. I believe, based on looking at the `Cargo.lock` file it is because Rocket's dependency on the `hyper` library specifies a dependency on the `log 0.3.9` library. For whatever reason it is not using the more recent `log=0.4.x`. That said, I don't know why it's pulling this library since, if I build it manually, it works fine.

```
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_nathanielford/2a39169ea9f6eb02fe788b12f9eae88f/external/raze__log__0_3_9/BUILD.bazel:27:1: error executing shell command: '/bin/bash -c CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR=$(pwd)/external/raze__log__0_3_9 external/rust_darwin_x86_64/bin/rustc "$@" --remap-path-prefix="$(pwd)"=__bazel_redacted_pwd  external/raze__log__0_3_9/src/lib.rs -...' failed (Exit 1) bash failed: error executing command /bin/bash -c 'CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR=$(pwd)/external/raze__log__0_3_9 external/rust_darwin_x86_64/bin/rustc "$@" --remap-path-prefix="$(pwd)"=__bazel_redacted_pwd' '' external/raze__log__0_3_9/src/lib.rs ... (remaining 24 argument(s) skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox
error[E0425]: cannot find function `set_logger` in crate `log`
   --> external/raze__log__0_3_9/src/lib.rs:731:16
    |
731 |     match log::set_logger(&ADAPTOR) {
    |                ^^^^^^^^^^ not found in `log`
    |
help: consider importing this function
    |
204 | use set_logger;
    |
```

The following is my directory structure:

```
/
|-WORKSPACE
|-BUILD      # Empty
|-web-api/
| |-BUILD
| |-src/
| | |-main.rs
| |-cargo/
|   |-Cargo.toml
|   |-Cargo.lock
|   |-BUILD.bazel
|   |-remote/
|     |-... (Cargo-raze files)
```

In order to set up the `cargo-raze` I did the following, following instructions from the [github page](https://github.com/google/cargo-raze).:

```
$ cd web-api/cargo
$ cargo generate-lockfile  
$ cargo vendor --versioned-dirs --locked
$ cargo raze
```

(The `generate-lockfile` is what creates the `Cargo.lock` file, and the `cargo raze` is what creates the `BUILD.bazel` file and all the contents of the `remote` sub directory.)

And then to execute the bazel build I go back to the root and run `bazel build //web-api`, which produces the above error.

This is my `WORKSPACE` file:

```
workspace(name = "rocket-bazel")

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "io_bazel_rules_rust",
    sha256 = "f21c67fc2fef9d57fa3c81fde1defd9e57d451883388c0a469ec1c470fd30dcb",
    strip_prefix = "rules_rust-master",
    urls = [
        "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_rust/archive/master.tar.gz"
    ],
)

http_archive(
    name = "bazel_skylib",
    sha256 = "9a737999532daca978a158f94e77e9af6a6a169709c0cee274f0a4c3359519bd",
    strip_prefix = "bazel-skylib-1.0.0",
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/archive/1.0.0.tar.gz",
)

load("@io_bazel_rules_rust//rust:repositories.bzl", "rust_repositories")
rust_repositories(version="nightly", iso_date="2020-06-02")

load("@io_bazel_rules_rust//:workspace.bzl", "bazel_version")
bazel_version(name = "bazel_version")

load("//web-api/cargo:crates.bzl", "raze_fetch_remote_crates")
raze_fetch_remote_crates()
```

This is my `web-api/BUILD` file:

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_rust//rust:rust.bzl", "rust_binary")

rust_binary(
    name = "web-api",
    srcs = ["src/main.rs"],
    deps = [
        "//web-api/cargo:rocket",
    ],
)
```

And my `web-api/cargo/Cargo.toml` file:

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_rust//rust:rust.bzl", "rust_binary")

rust_binary(
    name = "web-api",
    srcs = ["src/main.rs"],
    deps = [
        "//web-api/cargo:rocket",
    ],
)
```

I've run out of ideas as to what to try. I can get this to compile without Bazel, just using rust (though obviously the files are in slightly different places). I can get it to compile inside a Docker container. I just can't get Bazel (necessarily with cargo raze, either in vendor or remote mode) to run successfully: I assume that there is some mismatch in compile target or the nightly build that is not being properly set - but I'm not sure how to diagnose or get past that.

Here is a [link to a repository](https://github.com/nathanielford/bazel-rust-build) with the files/structure I tried.

Comment: Not sure if it would make sense (or if it is possible) to push your entire 'project' directory (make a repo on github) so people trying to help have somewhat easier entry when trying to understand the issue you're having.

Comment: @draganstankovic I have posted the MVE to github, and added a link to the question. Hopefully that might elucidate the matter!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue when I made a minimal Bazel workspace with rust and the *log* crate together with *env_logger* crate. I found a similar issue when you try to compile without *features = ["std"]*. I then tried to enable that in `Cargo.toml` on the *log* dependency without success.

My solution is that in `Cargo.toml` under `[raze]` I added:

```
default_gen_buildrs = true
```

I could trace it down to that when `default_gen_buildrs` flag is not set in the generated *log* crate the `BUILD.bazel` file did not have a *cargo_build_script* definition or this:

```
crate_features = [
      "std",
    ],
```